# Detail Mesh invisible on WebGL build

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, mesh, terrain, unity-webgl

I have a problem where detail meshes on the terrain I create are invisible on WebGL, they are visible in the Windows build, and inside Unity itself. I have added a screenshot showing the problem. As is shown, the shadows are still being cast.

[image: WebGL version]

[image: Unity/Windows version]

I have tried solving it by changing the models, its materials, and disabling several graphic settings, such as: Vertex Compression, Optimize Mesh Data, Colouring, GPU Instancing. The objects are visible when I don't place them using the Terrain Tool, however I don't want to resort to manually placing them.

Comment: Its odd 2 show. Its more like the others are up in the air.

Comment: @BugFinder I don't see them flying around, they are in the place they're supposed to be. As my water-shader also reacts to them.

Comment: What happens if you change graphics quality?

Comment: @BugFinder which settings do you mean exactly?

Comment: the "graphics quality" :) setting

Comment: as @BugFinder said, you need to find the reason why 2 stones are displayed. Do they have different materials, textures, LOD levels?

Comment: I changed both of the versions their graphic settings to the same (ultra). Asides from this, everything should be the same. It still gives the same result.